# How can I query data from smart contract data base?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

I mean not just printing data on the console, like in the documentation examples, or by `get_table_rows` API, but return it as function result, or maybe there is another way. The idea is that I need an action on that smart contract that will return an id for stored data when called from eosjs, and  then another action that using this id will return the actual data content.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a clever approach to me. You want to query data from witihn a smart-contract and use the (limited) on-chain-ressources you(or the users) have to return it to some off-chain-application. But there's no need to do this from within a smart-contract so without a real reason I don't see why someone should do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data in `eosjs` you won't use the smart contract for printing because it will cost you CPU time.

A good solution is to fetch it from the [**get_table_rows** API](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows) and then trigger an action from `eosjs`, that refers to the data. I would suggest using some fetching package like [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios). Then you can run something like this:

```
axios.post(<http://{host}:{port}/v1/chain/get_table_rows>, {
  code: <name of the smart contract>,
  table: <The name of the table to query>
}).then(
 (result) => {
   // do something with result.data
   // which will look like this
   // {
   // "rows": [
   //   {
   //     "account": "account",
   //     "balance": 1000
   //   }
   // ],
   // "more": false
   //}
 }
)
```

Another way could be using [`demux-js`](https://github.com/axios/axios) and maintain your own database. Then you could fetch it as you want.